# How to launch again the actual onCreate on Android?

Tags: android, launch, oncreate

For example, if i have a button called "Restart", and I want to launch again the onCreate where the app is actually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to restart the activity you're in, try this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're on API 11+, you can recreate an `Activity` by calling the [`recreate`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate%28%29) method:

```
activity.recreate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Finish the Activity and launch it again with an Intent, but I don't really see why you would want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing for Honeycomb (API 11) or later you can call [recreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the onPaint event with invalidate() if all you want to do is refresh.